# Node.js driver for Postgres-XL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgres-xl

Should the Node.js driver/connector for PostgreSQL be expected to function for Postgres-XL? What is the best way to connect to a Postgres-XL setup from Node.js?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://www.postgres-xl.org/faq/) states: _"Postgres-XL is wire-level protocol compatible with PostgreSQL.  That means Postgres-XL will work with any PostgreSQL-compatible driver"_.

Comment: If your [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) works with Postgres-XL, then any NodeJS driver will work just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres-XL is just the standard Postgres engine with a lot of distributed transactional over head options added so it can scale up to much large setups so you can use the standard Postgres driver.   You just want to make sure the versions match.